# UI Theme Choices Limited to Darcula and Default

Tags: pycharm

I just installed PyCharmCE 5.0.4 on a Mac and the UI color selection is different than available under Ubuntu. On the Mac the options for UI theme are Darcula and Default while under Ubuntu I have Darcula, GTK+, and IntelliJ (and no default). How do I get GTK+ and IntelliJ UI themes on the Mac?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is such thing like importing other themes but you can create your own theme: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=51945983

Comment: Thanks. I see that there are a lot of adjustments that can be made within the editor, but it looks like the IDE (specifically the surrounding panels and borders) are limited to just a few pre-defined themes. I would like to adjust colors in these surrounding areas.  For example, with the Darcula theme the font colors in the project panel are nearly illegible and it would be great to lighten the font colors displaying project elements.

Comment: I have it on OS X as well and it doesn't look that bad at all... :/ must be something weird with your installation maybe?

Comment: It looks like I somehow dorked up the color tables. I just reloaded PyCharm and it looks fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your answer wasn't the solution to the problem. I appreciate your comments though.